# Can some one explain this line of code from datepicker

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following Jquery script http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker

Now I'm making some adjustments and came across the following line of code, I'm not completely understanding it so can you tell me what's going on?

```
var fromUser = options.onRender(date);
var val = date.valueOf();
if (fromUser.selected || options.date == val || $.inArray(val, options.date) > -1 || (options.mode == 'range' && val >= options.date[0] && val <= options.date[1])) {
data.weeks[indic].days[indic2].classname.push('datepickerSelected');
}
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? It's a fairly generic list of conditions checking values from arrays and objects.

Comment: especially the last part starting at data.weeks till the classname push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//date picked by user
var fromUser = options.onRender(date); 
var val = date.valueOf();


if (fromUser.selected //if date is selected
    || options.date == val //date is set in options
    || $.inArray(val, options.date) > -1 //date exists in options
    || (options.mode == 'range' && val >= options.date[0] && val <= options.date[1])) //if date is in between the selected range of two pickers
{
    //mark the selected date by adding the class name of 'datepickerSelected' to the date-container in the picker
    data.weeks[indic].days[indic2].classname.push('datepickerSelected'); 
}
```

Comment: OP seems to know *what* this does, he wants to know *how* it does it.